# How to Unpivot table with merged cells?

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to do a little scheduling automation at my job.

I have a table that I'm not the one filling out. And it has merged cells in dates
[image: screenshot]

My formula causes empty cells to appear
=ArrayFormula(SPLIT(FLATTEN(MAIN!$D$4:$D$51&"|"&MAIN!$E$4:$E$51&"|"&MAIN!$F$3:$M$3&"| "&IF(MAIN!$F$4:$M$51=1,"Работает",MAIN!$F$4:$M$51)),"|",,))

[image: screenshot]

i need to get a flat table with correct dates

[image: screenshot]

Thanks!

see table https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1u-gD-f2e0MqoFnB7A8j-FoBiDkfvgSYjPSehuAcR79s/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Within your existing formula → Replace `MAIN!$D$4:$D$51` with `scan(;MAIN!D4:D51;lambda(a;c;if(c="";a;c)))` and you should be good to go*

```js
=ArrayFormula(SPLIT(FLATTEN(scan(;MAIN!D4:D51;lambda(a;c;if(c="";a;c)))&"|"&MAIN!$E$4:$E$51&"|"&MAIN!$F$3:$M$3&"| "&IF(MAIN!$F$4:$M$51=1;"Работает";MAIN!$F$4:$M$51));"|";;))
```

[image]

***Alternate formula*** if you wish to try:

```js
=reduce(tocol(;1);MAIN!F4:M51;lambda(a;c;vstack(a;hstack(index(scan(;MAIN!D1:D51;lambda(f;q;if(q="";f;q)));row(c));index(MAIN!E1:E51;row(c));index(MAIN!3:3;column(c));if(c=1;"Работает";c)))))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To unpivot such data, you need to:

1. Create a column with the dates where the dates are not merged, and fill in the blanks with the formula (propagated to all required rows):

   ```cpp
   =if(isblank(D4); A3; D4)
   ```

   [image: Suggested setup screenshot]
2. Use this new range in your formula instead of the range with merged dates.